# Maximum likelihood estimation for joint probability function

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, joint-distribution

**Background**

Suppose we want to look examine the viral load from individuals on drug therapy. In the study design, there are two groups. Group one receiving no treatment (or placebo) as the control and group two as the group receiving antiviral treatment. We compare the didferences in average reduction of viral load between the two groups.

Thus, let $x_1,...,x_n$ be the control group and $y_1,..., y_n$ be the group on antiviral therapy. In a scenario where there are equal observations of $n$ within each group, we assume the distribution for the control to be $\mathrm{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and those on the antiviral therapy to be distributed by $N(\mu + \delta, \sigma^2)$. $\delta$ denotes any additional reduction received from the antiviral treatment whilst $\mu$ denotes the mean reduction in absence of any treatment.

The hypotheses proposed are

\begin{align}
H_{0}: \delta = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad H_{1}:\delta \neq 0
\end{align}

**Question**

What is the log-likelihood function $\ell(\mu, \delta, z$) if $z = \sigma^2$ and thus determine the MLE for each parameter.

**Approach**

Consider the two normal distributions and their probability density functions for $x_i$ (no treatment) and $y_i$ (treatment) with equal variance $\sigma^2 = z$

\begin{align*}
    f_X(x) &= \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \mathrm{exp}\left\{-\frac{\left(x_i - \mu\right)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right\} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{z2\pi}} \mathrm{exp}\left\{-\frac{\left(x_i - \mu\right)^2}{2v}\right\} \\
    f_Y(y) &= \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \mathrm{exp}\left\{-\frac{\left(y_i - (\mu+\delta)\right)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right\} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{z2\pi}} \mathrm{exp}\left\{-\frac{\left(y_i - (\mu+\delta)\right)^2}{2v}\right\}
\end{align*}

The joint likelihood function would then be

\begin{align*}
    L(x,y) = \prod_{i = 1}^{n}f_{XY}(x,y) = \prod_{i = 1}^{n}f_X(x) \cdot \prod_{i = 1}^{n} f_Y(y)
\end{align*}

Taking the log of the likelihood function would result in the following
\begin{align}
    \ell(\mu,\delta,z|\mathbf{y}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\log f(x_i|\mu,z) + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\log f(y_i|\mu+\delta,z)
\end{align}

The resulting log-likelihood function would be
\begin{align}
    \ell(\mu,\delta,v|\mathbf{x_i,y_i}) = -\frac{n}{2}\log(2\pi z) - \frac{1}{2z}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\mu)^2 -\frac{n}{2}\log(2\pi z) - \frac{1}{2z}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-(\mu+\delta))^2
\end{align}

**Help**

I understand the next step to calculate the MLE to be taking the partial derivative with respect to each parameter $\mu, \delta, z$. However, I am having problems trouble shooting how to proceed. I am unsure if the approach I have taken to finding the joint likelihood function is correct. Any help would appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Assuming that this is a textbook exercise, then your approach for finding the joint log likelihood looks good - it appears you've assumed $X$ and $Y$ are independent. I'm not entirely sure why you've felt the need to include $v$. How is this different from $\sigma^2$ and $z$?

Comment: The textbook question appears to prompt you to find MLE by computing a joint log likelihood function. To find the MLE you need to *maximise* the joint log likelihood w.r.t. parameters. So after taking partial derivatives w.r.t. each parameter, set each of the three resulting expressions to 0 and solve for each parameter to get a function of the data, which is the desired estimator.

Comment: Thank you. I just need clarification regarding if the joint likelihood function was derived in a manner that was correct. Thank you again for the clarification on the maximisation of the score equation(s).